# how to send action form to two direction?

Tags: php, html

I have code send from to mail, and  I don't broke this code.
i don't know the page action receive the form info ..  I wont code send to tow direction, in the same time like this .

```html
<from action ="firstdiraction.php" action="seconddirction.php" >
```

Comment: Explain your question properly, can't get from what you have posted !

Comment: through php not possible. through javascript or jquery or ajax possible

Comment: how by jquery or ajax  , i wont send it  to database PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery and AJAX:

```
<form id="my_form" action="javascript:sendForm()">
  Form...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendForm() {
    var form = $('#my_form');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'firstdiraction.php',
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'seconddirction.php',
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });

  }
</script>
```

Comment: can i put php  dirction in jquery like this '<?php url : $script_url?$qs ?>'

Comment: url: '<?php $script_url?$qs ;?>',

Comment: @mohamedmoustafa Yes, you can, doing something like this: `url: '<?= $script_url ?>',`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to send form data to two different php scripts, this can be done via ajax like :

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
    $('#SubmitButton').click(function(){
        //Send data to the email script
        $.post( 'firstdiraction.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {
            //data is the result from the script
            alert(data);
        });

        //Send data to the other script
        $.post( 'seconddirction.php', $('form').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {
            //data is the result from the script
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Above will get triggered on press of submit button inside your form tag `<form> </form>`

`jQuery` aslo required, include it on your page.

Comment: This code won't work properly if he has more than one form

Comment: I believe OP wants to post single form to two scripts.